# Node.JS + MongoDB for real world Enterprise level application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am .NET developer and have been using .NET desktop (C # Win Forms, WPF) and web technologies (ASP.NET Web Forms , MVC , Silverlight) with SQL Server for development of enterprise applications.

Now for web development , everyone is talking about Node.js and NoSql database (MongoDB) and I have seen some examples too , some very impressive performance comparisons between Node.js vs MVC and SQL Server vs MongoDB... and clearly Node.js +MongoDB is rocking...

But my question is how reliable these technologies are for real world enterprise applications... all I have seen is some small examples which looks good.. but you kno when you develop real world web apps... things r different .. ASP.NET MVC gives you so much (security, IoC, Cache mang. etc with full OOP support and proven design patterns development support) to develop enterprise level application... can that all be achieved with Node.js ???

And whats about MongoDB... is it ready to be used as a dependable/scaleable database with all security requirements that come out of box in SQL Server ?

So in short the combo of Node.js + mongoDB is ready to be used in place of MVC 4 + Sql Server ?

Thanks,
Wasim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, yes and yes! Node.js has already been deployed in many large scale enterprise apps and is well supported, even on [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/). Here is a good article about node's enterprise worthiness: 
http://blog.appfog.com/node-js-is-taking-over-the-enterprise-whether-you-like-it-or-not/

As for mongodb, just look at their production deployments if you are worried:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments

The design patterns and approaches are different but the bottom line is that you can build highly scalable and performant enterprise apps with node.js and MongoDB.

Comment: Also you can read how EBay used node.js, I found it very interesting. http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2013/05/17/how-we-built-ebays-first-node-js-application/#.UuPGkRDn9hE